# PDFBox: Split PDF and add bookmarks IOException

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

In my project I split a pdf file by bookmarks. A new pdf file should be created containing the splitted pages and some new bookmarks.

This causes following exception:
**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?**

If I remove the line `outline.addLast(pagesOutline);` the new pdf contains the splitted pages (no exception) but obviously not the bookmarks. I think there is something wrong with the way I try to add bookmarks.

My code:

```
private void tryCreatePDF(List<String> listOfBookmarks) throws IOException
{
    document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/Users/me/Desktop/existingpdf.pdf"));
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDDocumentOutline bookmarksInExistingFile = catalog.getDocumentOutline();

    destinationPDF = new PDDocument();
    outline = new PDDocumentOutline();
    destinationPDF.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(outline);

    pagesOutline = new PDOutlineItem();
    pagesOutline.setTitle("First Bookmark");
    outline.addLast(pagesOutline);

    for(String bookmarkToSplit : listOfBookmarks)
    {
        addPagesFromExistingFileToNewPDF(bookmarksInExistingFile, bookmarkToSplit);
    }

    createNewPDF();
}

private void addPagesFromExistingFileToNewPDF(PDOutlineNode outlineNodeFromExistingPDF, String bookmarkToSplit) throws IOException
{
    PDOutlineItem current = outlineNodeFromExistingPDF.getFirstChild();

    while(current != null)
    {
        PDPage currentPage = current.findDestinationPage(document);
        Integer pageNumber = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().indexOf(currentPage) + 1;

        addPagesFromExistingFileToNewPDF(current, bookmarkToSplit);

        String bookmark = current.getTitle().trim();

        if(bookmark.matches(bookmarkToSplit + "\\s.+"))
        {
            Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

            splitter.setStartPage(pageNumber);
            splitter.setEndPage(pageNumber);

            List<PDDocument> pages = splitter.split(document);

            addPagesToNewDocument(pages);
        }

        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}

private void addPagesToNewDocument(List<PDDocument> pages) throws IOException
{
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();

    for(int index = 0; index < pages.size(); index++)
    {
        PDDocument doc = pages.get(index);

        pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(destinationPDF, doc);

        if(index == 0)
        {
            addNewBookmarkToNewPDF(doc);
        }

        doc.close();
    }
}

private void addNewBookmarkToNewPDF(PDDocument doc)
{
    PDPageFitWidthDestination dest = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
    dest.setPage(doc.getPage(0));

    PDOutlineItem bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
    bookmark.setDestination(dest);
    bookmark.setTitle("Child Bookmark");

    pagesOutline.addLast(bookmark);
}

private void createNewPDF() throws IOException
{
    File targetFile = new File("C:/Users/me/Desktop/newpdf.pdf");

    pagesOutline.openNode();
    outline.openNode();

    destinationPDF.save(targetFile);
    destinationPDF.close();

    document.close();
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.checkClosed(COSStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawInputStream(COSStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1203)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:383)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:522)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:460)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:444)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1099)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:419)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1370)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1257)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1267)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1238)
    at askstackoverflow.SplitPDFByBookmarks.createNewPDF(SplitPDFByBookmarks.java:126)
    at askstackoverflow.SplitPDFByBookmarks.tryCreatePDF(SplitPDFByBookmarks.java:55)
    at askstackoverflow.SplitPDFByBookmarks.<init>(SplitPDFByBookmarks.java:33)
    at askstackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

**Edit:**
@All the following readers of this question:
After solving the problem, my program doesn't work as I expected. (Every bookmark is pointing to the first page.) But this problem wasn't part of this question.

Comment: I suspect (only had a very quick look) closing in `addPagesToNewDocument()` is too early. This also closes resources from the source document. Better close only after all has been saved.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You're right, it works now. Thanks! I'll accept and upvote this if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: A plus one for the warning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing in `addPagesToNewDocument()` is too early. This also closes resources from the source document because these resources are used by both. Better start closing only after all documents have been saved.